# Handle Ruby on Rails resource when the singular is also plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, model, plural, singular

Whats the best way to handle a singular resource, that itself is plural.

For example a "settings page", that displays a selection of different settings. As I am displaying a single "Settings" instance, I would expect to use the show action, but would want to have "settings" not "setting" in the url.

If I called the resource "settings_group" it would solve the problem, but that name is far from catchy, and not an ideal solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to achieve this is to write it yourself:

```
resources :settings, :except => :show
match "settings/:id" => "settings#show", :as => :setting
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 2.x, you can do

```
resource :setting, :as => 'settings'
```

The generated URLs will use `setting`, though.